# Pyspotify: ImportError when importing spotify

Tags: python, spotify, raspberry-pi2

I am trying install and use pyspotify on raspberry pi. I followed the steps to 'install from source' on the pyspotify [site](https://pyspotify.mopidy.com/en/latest/installation/).

I then followed the Quickstart [doc](https://pyspotify.mopidy.com/en/latest/quickstart/) , initially just trying to import the spotify library and start a session. However, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/pi/projects/_main_.py", line 1, in <module>
   import spotify
 File "usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spotify/_init_.py", line 81, in <module>
   from spotify._spotify import ffi, lib # noqa
ImportError: libspotify.so.12: cannot  open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The library file libspotify.so.12 is sitting in the /usr/local/lib directory which is where I thought it should be.

Is this error because I have installed libspotify incorrectly? or likely that pyspotify isn't installed correctly?

I am using Python 2.7 and raspberry pi 2 with raspian wheezy.
Any help much appreciated, very new to the Raspberry pi and python.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone having the same issue with the raspberry pi, I have now followed the Debian Wheezy install instructions on the pyspotify [Site](https://pyspotify.mopidy.com/en/latest/installation/) and it now works. Lesson: try the easy way first.